# 2 simultaneous voltages from a transformer

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

I need a step down transformer that can give me 2 voltages simultaneously.
Primary will be 380vac and secondaries will need to be 24 vac and 12 vac. Instead of using 2 transformers, I would like to have a single transformer that supplies the 2 outputs as required.

I do not want to activate a switch or change any wiring. I need those 2 output voltages simultaneously at all times. I will never need one without the other.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: any 24V centre tapped can do that but not without VA specs

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly technically possible, either as two windings (12VAC and 24VAC) or as two 12VAC windings that can be connected in series to yield 12VAC to the common connection  and 24VAC total, or as a 24VAC center-tapped winding.

That does not necessarily mean you will be able to find, off the shelf and in stock, a relatively oddball primary voltage of 380VAC and those relatively common secondary voltages. The likelihood will be different depending on the VA involved, of course.

There's no particular issue in making such a transformer, if and you need sufficient quantity or are willing to pay for a small run of a special transformer, it can certainly be made.

Comment: Hello Spehro, many thanks for you answer. So if I understand you correctly, I should be able to achieve what I am looking for with a 400vac to 12vac transformer that has 2 x12V outputs?

Comment: Yes, provided you don't need isolation between the two outputs, of course.